# How to start migration if connectionstring adress is valid? / .Net Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I get database information from the user and if this information is correct and the connection is successfully established, I create the necessary connectionstring parameter to the appsettings.json file. There is no problem so far, but after this creation, I want to migrate the DataContext structure. But I don't know how to do this.

1. I wrote the necessary migration codes in the Program.cs file, but the project does not start because the connectionstring is null at the beginning.

[Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuLcC.jpg)

[Null Result on Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwpQo.jpg)

2. As you can see in the images above, because myconn is null, I cannot migrate with program.cs, so I need to start the migration process in the action where I control myconn.

[myconn action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVRmg.jpg)

First, I want to check the database information that the user has entered, and if it is valid, enter this information into the connectionstring field in appsetting.json and then do the necessary migration.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to database.  The log files can be found under the explorer Management Tab.  This should indicate the failure.  The login on SSMS can either be Windows Credentials (integrated security true in connection string) or SQL Credentials (username/password) in connection string.  Use same that is working in SSMS.  Also the login has Server\Instance which should be same as connection string. Also do query of a table with SSMS to make sure you have permission to read/write database.

Comment: Hi @onurkul, if you want to dynamically migrate the database, you can put your code of migration to your action.

Comment: @Rena That's exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help?

Comment: Hi @onurkul, you can inject the DbContext to your controller and use `context.Database.Migrate()` when the connection string is nut null.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to check your connection string is valid. if your connection string is not valid then create your connection string with your default values then you can run your method. If there is a error before app fully initialized you can't route your actions.

Check your connectionstring is valid:

```
public bool CheckConnectionIsValid(string cnnStr){
    try {
        //This will check your connectionstring format
        DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.ConnectionString = cnnStr;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in your startup:

```
//before app build
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconn");
if(CheckConnectionIsValid(connectionString))
{
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}

//after app build
if(CheckConnectionIsValid(connectionString))
{
    //your migration code here
}
```

In first run your connectionstring will be null so database not initalized but your app will not throw error. So you can call your action.
If your app configuration updated your app will restart and in second time your app migrate new db

Comment: So how can I call this method that I created for control to program.cs? Now I have completed the necessary steps, but I don't know how to call the method I created to program.cs. Can you help with this?

Comment: You can create this method static so create this method in new class and add to your namespaces. Then you can use it in your Program.cs